# java lexicographically sort three words

Tags: java

I'm new to the Java programming language and want to create a program that reads in three words using scanner class and lexicoggraphically order the three words doing this in the main method for example user enters Tom Harry Dick, answer should be Dick Harry and Tom.. I tried to use an if statement to compare the strings using java compareTo() but if statement wont return anything for me since the main method is void.

```
public class SortWords {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    String firstWord;
    String secondWord;
    String thirdWord;


    System.out.println("Enter three words seperated by white space");

    firstWord = userInput.next();
    System.out.println(firstWord);

    secondWord = userInput.next();
    System.out.println(secondWord);

    thirdWord = userInput.next();
    System.out.println(thirdWord);

}
```

}

Comment: _I tried to use an if statement to compare the strings using java compareTo() but if statement wont return anything for me since the main method is void._ Quite new to Java, hu?

Comment: I'm definitely not good at it. lol I'm trying though, Java is a lot of fun.

Comment: Pretty sure you just need to `System.out.println()` the words in sorted order. Don't take the word return too literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then try to read as an array elements then sort that array

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] strings = new String[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < strings .length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter name");
        strings [i] = input.next();
    }
}

Arrays.sort(strings);
```

Comment: This is program has to be written using the Scanner class reading input.

Comment: String[] strings = new double[3]; incompatible types?

Comment: Yeah figured, where exactly is the numbers.length variable coming from ?

Comment: Yeah great code, need to learn more about the Arrays.sort going to check out the tutorials on oracle.  I had to add System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings)); at the end to print the sorted order but works fine, thanks.

Comment: One last thing is there a method in the Arrays that also checks the validity and order of the Capital letter to Lowercase letter and checks for hierarchy when sorting?

Comment: This seemed to work for anyone who's interested in it for future use  Arrays.sort(strings, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));

Answer (score 1):

"I tried to use an if statement to compare the strings using java compareTo() but if statement wont return anything for me since the main method is void."

This is incorrect.

First, we do not say an if statement 'returns anything', we say that it chooses to either execute its statement block or not (the one enclosed by `{` `}`) based on whether its condition (enclosed by `(` `)`) evaluates to true or false. (Similar idea when `else` and `else if` are thrown in)

Second, this is not effected by the return type of the method it's in, since it has nothing to do with return.

You should use print and println statements to print out the results of your comparisons of the three strings, since this is the `main` method and there is no higher method to return to.